# nodejs pyramid of doom solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been looking for a solution to my pyramid of doom. what I have come up with so far is the following:

```
router.use('/create',
function(res,req,next)
{
 try
    {
        var data =
            {
                startDate: new Date(req.body.startDate),
                endDate: new Date(req.body.endDate),
                details: req.body.details,
                file:req.body.file,
                filename:req.body.filename,
                fileType:req.body.fileType
            };
        res.data = data;
        next()
    }catch(e)
    {
        res.end(JSON.stringify({complete:"false",error:e}));
        return;
    }
},
function(res,req,next){...},
function(res,req,next)
{
    if(res.status.file)
   {
    var sql = "";
    sql = 'insert into attachments values(' + id + ',"' + data.file + '","' + data.filename + '","' + data.fileType + '");';

    db.exec(sql, function(err)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            res.end(JSON.stringify({
                complete: "false",
                error: err + " Contact 1-915-400-0823 NOW this left dirty data in the database"
            }));
            return;
        }
        res.delegateID = this.lastID;
        next()
    });
   }
   else
   {
       next()
   }
},
function(res,req,next){...},
function(res,req,next){...},
);
```

Each function does one task of updating the database, sending out emails and validating. I'm using `next()` after each callback to call the next function down the stream; skipping any task that is not needed. Is this a good solution or should I be using something else?

Comment: Promises are probably a good start to solve the pyramid of doom problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Summary

Based on the code that you've posted it looks like you should be making use of a *Generator Function*.

## About

The Generator Function returns an iterable. You then use the `.next()` function to advance the Generator, which will pause at either the completion of the function or a `yield` statement.

In your case the code would be refactored into a single `function*` with `yield` statements where you need it to wait for data. You could then call `.next()` upon the receipt of that data and advance to the next portion of the function.

I'd also recommend that you take a look at *Promises*. Then you can run the generator until the `yield` statement and return a promise from it. Only advance to the next `yield` statement once the returned promise has resolved.

Comment: I added some more code to make it a little clearer on whats going on. So what you are saying is that the method I have used is not asynchronously running or not doing it very effectively?

Comment: From what I can tell the code is not running in an asynchronous manner. However, as you're running SQL queries you may want to avoid running the code in async. Does it matter what order the queries are executed in? If _yes_, use non-async code; if _no_, it would best be written in async.

Comment: The order does matter. Do you have any recommendation for this kind of problem

Comment: I'd still use a generator function and promises; just set it up so that you;re only advancing the iterator when the previous promise resolves. I've updated my answer to show this.